# Is it possible to ask if there any params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following code:

```
<% if params[:country].present? %>
  <%= link_to 'Clear Filters', users_path %>
<% end %>
```

works correctly, however instead of having to list each param from my model is there a DRY way to rewrite the above code as `if params[any].present?`

I have tried the following without success:

```
if params.present? 
if params.any? 
if params[].present? 
if params[''].present?
unless params.empty?
```

Comment: There is an .any? method, for enumerables in ruby, have you tried that?, also .empty? could work

Comment: I edited the question. These do not work.

Comment: I think that you need to check all of the params you need to make sure that are not present using the param.keys property, check the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**params** is a hash, so you can use any hash method in it, like **any?**, or **empty?** and you can access keys and values as well but rails haves a helper for conditional links [link_to_if](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to_if) so your example could be like:

```ruby
<%= link_to_if params[:country].present?, 'Clear Filters', users_path %>
```

or if you would like to know if there are any params

```ruby
<%= link_to_if params.any?, 'Clear Filters', users_path %>
```

Of course, there is also items on your params variable, such as **controller** etc if you have a group of params to check you could always do:

```ruby
<%= link_to_if (params.keys & filters).empty?, 'Clear Filters', users_path %>
```

This is what the [& operator](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-26) does. As for the **filters**, you can use any option to pass data to the view to have it, either instance variables on controller(not recommended, cause it's not part of the logic) place a method on a helper(could work) or a constant on a model(I prefer that)

If you choose to leave it on a helper you can add it to the **users_helper** it makes sense cause it will *help* to layout your view wich is definitely why helpers are for:

```ruby
# helpers/users_helper.rb
def filters
  ['country', 'height', 'age']
end
```

But again you could probably use those values somewhere else, specifically, where you would actually filter the values i assume it is a responsibility of the model to filter those, so you can put it in your model and it could be like this:

```ruby
# models/user.rb
...
FILTERS = ['country', 'height', 'age']
...

#your view
<%= link_to_if (params.keys & User::FILTERS).empty?, 'Clear Filters', users_path %>
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? you can check the keys and search for the filters you are looking for?

Comment: I got this to work if i replace filter_param_symbols with ["country"] but I cannot get it to work as a method. how should it be setup?

Comment: The methods on the views are provided on the helpers, never the less if this is a case when you wanna filter records of a certain model, i would suggest to place some sort of constant on your model so you to use it, i'll update my answer.

Comment: What is this called again where we use the capitalized letters = and then an array. I have seen it many times now but would like to read the documentation to better understand it thanks

Comment: Is just a convention , to name class constants or properties with capital letters

Comment: While it's an implementation detail that doesn't mater in this context of this question, params is actually not a hash in Rails 5. [This PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/20868) is where it was changed and explains why the core team made the change.

Answer (score 2):

The [Rails router](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#static-segments) builds up the params using information request path. In addition to params you add (either explicitly of from a `form_for`), `params` also includes keys that contain which controller and action are being used to render the view.

For example, if you have a blog and are rendering the path `/articles/1`, the params will include:

```
{
  controller: "articles",
  action: "show",
  id: 1
}
```

So `params.present?` and `params.any?` are actually working as expected because your params are actually not empty.

To answer your question, there are a few approaches you could take to DRY up your code. You could use a write a [helper method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers.html) that checks the `params` to see if location (and whatever other attributes you care about) are present and then use that in the conditional in your view.